# How to decrypt files encrypted with Crypto Defense, I have the key(s)

Tags: decryption

I have a client who is a victim of the Crypto Defense randomware virus. Thankfully I was able to find the keys but the thing is I have no idea **HOW** to use those keys to decrypt their files.

So...

How do I use the keys to decrypt the client's files?

This includes what software I need to use for example.

Comment: The malware itself should provide the capabilities.  If it does not then your client is out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

How did you find the key? My understanding is that complete instructions are included as a text file. If you found the key, look for the instructions.

I also found this link that may be helpful:
http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/cryptodefense-ransomware-information

Good luck!